# TypeError: sheet.getDataRange is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following google-script with the intention to sort the columns by column 15 every time the file is opened:

```
function autoSort(sheet) {
  var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 15;
  var ASCENDING = true;
  var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 1;
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}

function onOpen(event) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  autoSort(event.source);
  }
```

The script seems to work, but I regularly get emails with the following error:

> TypeError: sheet.getDataRange is not a function

I couldn't figure out what the problem is even why searching online and on stackoverflow.

How do I solve the issue?

Comment: Probably because sheet is not an instance of Class Sheet.  Since we can't see where the parameter came from we can't know for sure

Comment: Using offset like you have done will result in offsetting the entire range which will result in pushing the last row in the range down below data.  So  you might want to use [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: the variable sheet is being set by `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");` Isn't that a class sheet?

Comment: Class SpreadsheetApp does not have a method named getSheetByName() but class Spreadsheet does. [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))

Answer (score 2):

You need to redefine your `sheet` object.

From:

```
function onOpen(event) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  autoSort(event.source);
}
```

To:

```
function onOpen(event) {
  autoSort(event.source.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"));
}
```

or

```
function onOpen(event) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
 autoSort(sheet);
}
```

Comment: I did that and the script is working, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @ToDo i gave you 2 options. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I used the second option because I remembered that it used to be like that before I modified it. It works, but the error remains. Can you explain what the first function does?

Comment: @ToDo I assume you are familiar with how onOpen works. You don't execute it manually. It triggers itself when you open the spreadsheet file that the script is attached to. Also autoSort(sheet) can not be executed as a standalone function because it depends on the parameter sheet. So you can't test the full code by executing either function. The proper way is to just open the spreadsheet file and let it do its job.

Comment: If you want to execute the first function as a standalone function, get rid of the parameter sheet inside the parenthesis. Therefore make it
 autoSort() and within that function define the sheet parameter as I explain in the second solution: var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")